# Nginx server with uwsgi,flask and sleekxmpp

Tags: nginx, flask, xmpp, uwsgi, sleekxmpp

I'm trying to handling some messages by using nginx server with uwsgi, flask and sleekxmpp.
Here is the code.

```
import ssl, json, logging, threading, time
from flask import Flask
from sleekxmpp import ClientXMPP
from sleekxmpp.exceptions import IqError, IqTimeout

smsg = """{
        "version":1,
        "type":"request",
        "messageId":"xxyyzz",
        "payload":
        {
                "deviceType":"ctlr",
                "command":"getDeviceInfo"
        }
}"""


class XMPP(ClientXMPP):

    rosterList=[]

    def __init__(self, jid, password):
        ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password)

        self.add_event_handler('session_start', self.session_start, threaded = True)
        self.add_event_handler('message', self.message, threaded=True)
        self.ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23

    def session_start(self, event):
        self.send_presence(pshow='online')

        try:
            self.rosterList.append(self.get_roster())
        except IqError as err:
            print 'Error: %' % err.iq['error']['condition']
        except IqTimeout:
            print 'Error: Request time out'

    def message(self, msg):
        data = msg['body'][12:]
        dictData = json.loads(data)
        print data
        if 'payload' in dictData.keys():
            for lists in dictData['payload']['indexes']:
                print lists
        elif 'message' in dictData.keys():
            print 'Request accepted'

app = Flask(__name__)

#logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)
xmpp = XMPP('jid', 'password')

class XmppThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        if xmpp.connect(('server', '5222')):
            xmpp.process(block=True)

xt = XmppThread()
xt.start()

@app.route('/')
def send():
    xmpp.send_message(mto='receiver', mbody=smsg, mtype='chat')
    return '<h1>Send</h1>'
```

I run the code by uwsgi with these options.

```
[uwsgi]
uid = uwsgi
gid = uwsgi
pidfile = /run/uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
emperor = /etc/uwsgi.d
stats = /run/uwsgi/stats.sock
chmod-socket = 660
emperor-tyrant = true
cap = setgid,setuid


[uwsgi]
plugin = python
http-socket = :8080
wsgi-file = /var/www/uwsgi/flask_uwsgi.py
callable = app
module = app
enable-threads = True
logto = /var/www/uwsgi/flask_uwsgi.log
```

When I run uwsgi by typing command, like '/usr/sbin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini', it works well. I can send and recieve the messages. But, when I run this on CentOS 7's service, recieve is working, but send is not working.
Did i need some more options or missing something?